# Adding a link to Idiomatic Text element

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

This is my html code

```
<a id="youtube" href="#">
<i class="fab fa-youtube-square"></i>
</a>
```

This is my js code

```
let lyrics =
[
    {
        lyric: '"lyrics goes here"',
        artist: '- artist',
        link: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ox7RsX1Ee34" 
    },
]

let button = document.getElementById("button")

let lyric = document.getElementById("lyric")

let artist = document.getElementById("artist")

let link = document.getElementById("youtube")

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * lyrics.length)
    lyric.innerHTML = lyrics[random].lyric;
    artist.innerHTML = lyrics[random].artist;
    link.innerHTML= lyrics[random].link;
})
```

[This is what it looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6JMJ.png)

When I press the youtube button I want it to take me to the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send the user to the url of the youtube video, use `window.open`:

```js
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * lyrics.length);
    lyric.innerHTML = lyrics[random].lyric;
    artist.innerHTML = lyrics[random].artist;

    window.open(lyrics[random].link);
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could set the `href` of the link and then click it to go to the page:

```js
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * lyrics.length);
    lyric.innerHTML = lyrics[random].lyric;
    artist.innerHTML = lyrics[random].artist;

    link.href = lyrics[random].link;
    link.click();
}
```

and to make it open in a new tab: `<a id="youtube" target="_blank">`